# how to set up github authentication with drf and vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, github, django-rest-framework

I followed this[tutorial](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and i was able to create view for github:
[image: github login]

if i put social auth token, i am able to retrieve the original token.
I am looking for ways to implement this process inside vuejs.
can i do something similar to this:

```
    onGoogleSignInSuccess (resp) {
      const token = resp.Zi.access_token
      axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/google/', {
        access_token: token
      })
        .then(resp => {
          this.user = resp.data.user
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.response)
        })
    },
```